# Display date in localized format in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-date-format

I have a scenario in which I have to set a date for event, the date picker should take the date format in localized format according to country or region. How can I do that in AngularJS? I have tried many solutions but didn't find any appropriate one.

Comment: How do you intend to determine a user's "country or region"? In the globalised world of the internet, using regions or languages for localisation to determine formatting preferences is becoming less and less reliable. Far better to just use an unambiguous format.

Comment: Have you tried with moment JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toLocaleDateString()

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

```js
var today = new Date();

var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

 console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US'));
 console.log(today.toLocaleDateString('en-US'));
```

Comment: The output from [*toLocaleDateString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring) is implementation dependent and support is unreliable. Far better to use a parsing and formatting library.